# Does StringContent get disposed with HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

`StringContent/HttpContent` are disposable as well as `HttpRequestMessage` I'm wondering if the request `StringContent` gets disposed when the `HttpRequestMessage` gets disposed or if I need two separate `using` or if there's a better way to dispose these? For example

```
var content = new StringContent("test");

 using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri))
 {

        requestMessage.Content = content;

        var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Would this need to be:

```
using(var content = new StringContent("test"))
{

     using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri))
     {
    
            requestMessage.Content = content;
    
            var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should verify the response's `Content-Type` and status-code match your expectations before reading the response body btw.

Comment: Yeah its just a quick rough example, wouldn't normally do this

Comment: Your code disposes the `HttpRequestMessage`, _not_ the `HttpResponseMessage` btw - and your question title says `HttpResponseMessage` but your post's body concerns `HttpRequestMessage`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(At the time of writing, the OP's question is ambiguous as to whether they're referring to `HttpRequestMessage` or `HttpResponseMessage`, so I'll describe both).

- `HttpRequestMessage.Dispose()`:

  - Disposes of only the **request**'s `Content`.
  - [See the source code here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpRequestMessage.cs#L200).
- `HttpResponseMessage.Dispose()`:

  - Disposes of **only** its `response.Content`.
  - It **does not** dispose of `response.RequestMessage` or the `HttpRequestMessage` in any other way.

    - It, therefore, does not dispose of the `HttpRequestMessage.Content` either.
  - [See the source code here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpResponseMessage.cs#L197).

You should not dispose of the `HttpRequestMessage` until *after* the `HttpClient` has *fully* finished sending your request (I believe there are some (rare) cases where you get a `HttpResponseMessage` back even if the request's content has not finished being sent yet - like when using exotic transfer-encoding schemes or multi-part requests) - but it's generally best to assume *nested lifetimes* of all objects involved, so _if `System.Net.Http` were perfect (which it isn't) then you'd do this:

1. Ensure the request/response is fully completed.
2. Dispose of the response content first.
3. Then the `HttpResponseMessage`.
4. Then the request's content.
5. Then the `HttpRequestMessage`.
6. Then the `HttpClient`.

...however as disposing of content is implicit when you dispose of the parent request/response message (and you *probably* shouldn't call `HttpClient.Dispose` either), so just do this:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = this.httpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient()) // Only dispose HttpClient instances created by IHttpClientFactory. *DO NOT DISPOSE* of other HttpClient instances unless you know what you're doing!
using (HttpContent reqContent = new StringContent("test")) // Disposing of this HttpContent is unnecessary (as it's disposed when `request` is disposed).
using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri) { Content = reqContent })
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false)) // Note there is no `using()` block for the HttpContent object, this is because we don't "own" the object, the HttpResponseMessage does.
{
    String responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    return responseBody;
}
```

---

Though remember that the `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage` objects are separate, so you can dispose of your `HttpRequestMessage` but still return the `HttpResponseMessage` (or vice-versa!) (though you *cannot* return the `Stream` from `ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStream()` if you do dispose of the `HttpResponseMessage` - so if you need to return a `Stream` you should subclass `Stream` and wrap the returned `stream` but don't dispose the `HttpResponseMessage` and instead dispose of it *inside* your `Stream` subclass's `Dispose` method.

```
public async Task<Stream> GetStreamAsync()
{
    using( HttpClient httpClient = this.httpClientFactory.CreateHttpClient() )
    using( HttpContent reqContent = new StringContent("test") )
    using( HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Post, requestUri) { Content = reqContent })
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await this.httpClient.SendAsync( request ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        try
        {
            Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            return new StreamWithDependencies( stream, response ); // See `class StreamWithDependencies` below.
        }
        catch // <-- When returning an IDisposable you should only dispose of things in `catch`, not in a `finally`.
        {
            response.Dispose(); // <-- Doing this means `response` (and `response.Content` will always be disposed) *and* can optionally outlive the method's scope if it follows the happy-path.
            throw; // <-- Don't swallow any exceptions, re-throw them (don't use `throw ex;` as that resets the StackTrace, always use either `throw;` (without a name) or throw a new exception with the caught exception passed as the `Exception.InnerException`.)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of what `class Stream2` could look like: the main points are that it proxies `Stream`, and that its `Dispose` method will dispose of other objects you tell it to.

```
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.IO;

class StreamWithDependencies : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream subject;
    private readonly ImmutableList<IDisposable> disposeWith;

    public StreamWithDependencies( Stream subject, params IDisposable[] disposeWith )
    {
        this.subject = subject ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(subject));
        this.disposeWith = ( disposeWith ?? Array.Empty<IDisposable>() ).ToImmutableList();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(Boolean disposing)
    {
        if( disposing )
        {
            this.subject.Dispose();
            foreach( IDisposable d in this.disposeWith )
            {
                d.Dispose();
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public override Int32 Read(...)  => this.subject.Read( ... ):
    pubiic override Task<Int32> ReadAsync( ... ) => this.Subject.ReadAsync( ... );
    // etc
    // Only implement and forward methods for reading, no need to implement methods for writing.
}
```

Comment: if the request disposes the HttpContent/StringContent automatically, shouldn't it be fine to NOT explicitly add a `using` to the request content?

Comment: @joe Correct. I did it for visual consistency reasons. But yes, **it is optional**.

Comment: Ok great, so the first example I gave where the StringContent was outside the `using` block and wasn't wrapped in its own `using` should be safe to assume that the content is properly disposed of? I would also obviously need to add a using to the response message as well but just for demonstration purposes it was omitted

Comment: @joe _Sort-of_, the problem is that your code (in that example) does not handle the case of the `HttpRequestMessage` ctor throwing, in which case the `Content` will not be disposed (because it isn't attached to any request, and because exceptions in failed ctors do not cause `Dispose` to be invoked, it's all-or-nothing).

Comment: Right so to cover all bases and safely dispose of the content it needs to be in its own `using`?

Comment: I'm creating the content from a separate utility method hence the extra variable

Comment: "Right so to cover all bases and safely dispose of the content it needs to be in its own `using`?" - **yes, exactly**.

Comment: Though remember that the `HttpRequestMessage` and `HttpResponseMessage` objects are separate, so you can dispose of your `HttpRequestMessage` but still return the `HttpResponseMessage` (or vice-versa!) (though you _cannot_ return the `Stream` from `ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStream()` if you do dispose of the `HttpResponseMessage` - so if you need to return a `Stream` you should subclass `Stream` and wrap the returned `stream` but don't dispose the `HttpResponseMessage` and instead dispose of it _inside_ your `Stream` subclass's `Dispose` method.