# c# StringContent in MultipartFormDataContent seems to have been disposed at the point of doing PostAsync

Tags: c#, objectdisposedexception

I have the following pretty simple class for sending some data to an external supplier, what seems to happen is at the point of the `_httpClient.PostAsync` call something(?) has already disposed of the StringContent objects -

```
public async Task<SendResponse> SendMessageAsync(SendRequest request)
{

    var httpContent = MapLocally(request);

    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("email/3/send", httpContent);
    var actualResponse = await HandleResponseAsync<SendResponse>(response, "message/send");        

    return _responseMapper.Map(actualResponse!);
}

private MultipartFormDataContent MapLocally(SendEmailRequest request)
{
    using var fromContent = new StringContent("beakersoft@gmail.com");
    
    return new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        { fromContent, "from" },            
    };
}
```

I don't get passed the `PostAsync` line and it just exceptions with

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream.
```

and

```
ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
```

If I remove the `using` statement in the fromContent variable then it works ok, and same if I move the declaration of the variable from the MapLocally method to the SendMessageAsync, declare it (along with its using statement) and pass it into MapLocally.

I dont want to not have the using statement in the MapLocally method as that throws compiler warnings, and I don't want my mapping code in the SendMessageAsync method either.

I cant really understand what's going on, anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

Not surprising, as you're explicitly disposing the `StringContent` when `MapLocally()` returns by putting `using` in front of its declaration.

You could just remove `using` and it should be fine.

If you want to be slightly more clear about cleaning up the `StringContent` you remove `MapLocally()` and put the contents of it just above `var response = ...` instead, but in this case this [isn't really necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69029065/does-stringcontent-get-disposed-with-httpresponsemessage) (and a simple `PostAsync()` does the same).